# jQuery set input value attribute based on selected option on page load

Tags: jquery

I need to set an input's value attribute to the option selected in the select menu

```
<select id="choice">
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
</select>
<input type='text' id="other" class="test" value=""/>
```

The jQuery i'm using is

```
var option = $('#choice').find(":selected").text();
$('#other').val(option);

$('#choice').change(function () {
    var selected_item = $(this).val()
    $('#other').val(selected_item);
    $('#other').attr('value', $('#choice').val())
});
```

This set the input value on page load. The value attribute though is only set on the .change event. I need the value attribute of the input to also be set when the page loads to the currently select option.

http://jsfiddle.net/peter/LaTXG/2/

Thanks

Comment: A text input val is the same as its attr("value"). I don't understand your issue as it works for me. if I add selected attr to one of the choices it is added to the textbox onload

Comment: _"I need the value attribute of the input to also be set"_, `value` is a property, it is value property that is sent to the server not the value attribute, read about DOM and `val` method.

Comment: @undefined how is this not a real question?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#choice').on('change', function () {
    $('#other').val(this.value);
}).trigger('change');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/LaTXG/3/)

Will set the text inputs value to the selects value, both on pageload and change.

Answer (score -1):

Use setTimeout

```
setTimeout(function(){
var option = $('#choice').find(":selected").val();
$('#other').val(option);
},500);
```